# How to use flexbox to align some blocks

Tags: html, css, flexbox, alignment

Basically I want to achieve this:

[image]

I have 4 blocks:

```
<div style="width: auto;">1</div>
<div style="width: 13px;">2</div>
<div style="width: 45px;">3</div>
<div style="width: 45px;">4</div>
```

Currently I don't have any styling on block 1,3,4 and I keep a float right on the 2nd block and it looks good, but I want to achieve this using css `flex`.

How can I achieve this? Thanks

UPDATE: The reason why I did not mark any answer as complete was that I managed to find a good solution before any answer was posted and it was lighter also. The only thing that I did was to set `display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;` on the container `div` and `flex-grow: 1;` on the first child.

Comment: Any Specific reason using flexbox ?

Comment: You obviously missed my point....

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps!

You can't use `float` inside flex container and the reason is that float property does not apply to flex-level boxes.

You can achieve this by setting `order` for each `div`.And `margin-left:auto` for `2nd div`.

```css
.box{
  background-color:green;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  width:61px;
  padding:5px;
}
.box>div{
  background-color:pink;
}
.box>div:nth-child(2){
  margin-left: auto;
    order: 2;
}
.box>div:nth-child(3){
    order: 3;
}
.box>div:nth-child(4){
    order: 4;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
<div style="width: auto;">1</div>
<div style="width: 13px;">2</div>
<div style="width: 45px;">3</div>
<div style="width: 45px;">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you need to read up on flex items, `order` and _order_ by markup.

Comment: sure.Thanks@LGSon

Answer (score 0):

you need to wrap your boxes in a container so you can adjust alignments via flex property like so:

```css
div:not(.container){
  height:50px;
  background:#333;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  color:#fff;
}
.container{
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}
.container{
      justify-content: space-between;
}

.div1{
  flex:0 0 15%;
}
.div2{
  flex:0 0 40%;
}
.div3,.div4{
  flex:0 0 60%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="div1" >1</div>
  <div class="div2" >2</div>
  <div class="div3">3</div>
  <div class="div4">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't change the html code structure, can't use container1, container2..

Comment: the property `display:flex` should  be on the parent not on the elements so we should have a parent

Comment: True but all my divs are contained into just 1 parent - container, not 2